# Conditional ssl_verify_client in NGINX

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to enable client certificate verification only for requests from outside of our intranet without verification for requests from, for example, 192.168.0.0/24. I tried to use `geo` module to define variable for internal subnet.
In `http` context:

```
geo $intranet { 
  default 0; 
  192.168.0.0/24 1; 
}
```

In `server` context

```
if ($intranet != 1) { 
  ssl_verify_client on; 
}
```

but it is impossible to use `ssl_verify_client` directive inside `if` statement. I get an error:

> "ssl_verify_client" directive is not allowed here

Is there other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found solution which works as expected.

In `http` context:

```
geo $intranet { 
  default 0; 
  192.168.0.0/23 1; 
}
```

In `server` context:

```
ssl_verify_client optional;

set $verify $intranet$ssl_client_verify;

if ($verify ~ (0NONE|0FAILED)) {
  return 403;
}
```